# extract values from sql insert statement in java

Tags: java, sql, split

how i can extract values from from sql insert statement:

for example :

```
INSERT INTO `mtable` VALUES (639383,-216,-398,1,174431,'test , test',1239629);
```

i try to use split with ( , ) but the problem if the value contain ( , ) character

```
line = line.trim().replace("INSERT INTO `mtable` VALUES (", "").replace(");", "");
String []vals = line.split(",");
```

i need values like that :

```
639383
-216
398
1
174431
test , test
239629
```

Comment: To do it the right way you will need a parser like this: http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution, it is not full proof and will break on corner conditions in its current shape, you can enhance it as per your usage:

```
    String s = "INSERT INTO `mtable` VALUES (639383,-216,-398,1,174431,'test , test',1239629);";

    s = s.replaceAll(".*\\((.*)\\);", "$1");

    String[] strs = s.split("'");

    for (String string : strs) {
        if(string.endsWith(",") || string.startsWith(",")) {
            String[] splits = string.split(",");
            for (String string2 : splits) {
                if(string2!=null && string2.trim().length()!=0) {
                    System.out.println(string2);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
639383
-216
-398
1
174431
test , test
1239629
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = line.trim().substring("(",")");
String[] b =a.spilt(",");
```